# Rendering frames off sequence

Tags: rendering, motion-blur

Okay so the gist is, I'm rendering an animation in Eevee with motion blur, the problem with that is whenever I make a jump cut, the 2 transition frames get blurred, so I re-render those 2 without motion blur, simple enough.

So now I have to do this about a 40 times, is there any way I can tell blender to render frames 101 to 102 and then 501 to 502 and so on instead of resetting the frame range every 5 minutes? Or does blender not support that kind of thing yet?

(I'm aware cycles has a method of fixing the motion blur using the position but this doesn't work in Eevee)

Comment: You could try holding everything in place for a frame or two and cut them out later in post.

Comment: Have you tried using markers in the timeline to switch cameras? (**M** adds a marker and **Ctrl B** will bind the selected marker to the selected camera)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can use the command line for this.

To render only the transition frames :

```
blender -b c:/mypath/myfile_without_mblur.blend -f 101,102,501,502
```

To render in-between frames :

```
blender -b c:/mypath/myfile_with_mblur.blend -f 1..100,103..500
```

[Command line rendering documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/render.html)